# Why doesn't ng-repeat detect parent scope function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Why do I have to use

`e in $parent.parentScopeFunc()`

instead of

`e in parentScopeFunc()`

when

`{{ parentScopeValue }}`

works fine for displaying parent scope members in a template?

Comment: Can we see an example?

Comment: @RahilWazir Coming up with a generalized example isn't as simple as it seemed at first. In attempting to create one, I inadvertently created an example of this problem *not* occurring at http://plnkr.co/edit/oC86CKiMM18k5XUIInzo

Answer (score 3):

You're either overriding that function in whichever directive it's failing in or the function is not initialized in the parent scope until after the child scope is created.